# Subdivide a face by connecting opposite vertices

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces

Is there a way to subdivide a face like this? There is a lot of opposite vertices, it takes too much time to connect them manually.

[image: example]

The best way I found was triangulate (Ctrl-T) but it does only a half of job and requires a lot of manual edit.

If it is not possible to have done automatically, what would be the easiest method?

Thanks!

Comment: Delete the Ngon and fill with Ctrl+F

Comment: Yes, delete the face, then Ctrl F > Grid Fill, maybe you'll have to play with the parameters on the bottom of the left menu (displayed with T) to correctly fulfill

Comment: If you wan to do it manually you can use vertex select an connect the opposing vertices with the [**vertex connect path**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/vertex_connect.html?highlight=vertex%20connect%20path)  tool (keyboard shorcut: **J**)

Comment: @moonboots & Cegaton you should both post it as an answer so that when people google it they can find an answer quick.

Comment: @moonboots as your solution is more complete, could you add it as an answer, i will mark it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the face, select the vertices around the hole, then Ctrl F > Grid Fill. Maybe you'll have to play with the parameters available on the bottom of the left menu (displayed with T) to correctly fulfill.